# Twitter callback URL from DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j, android-dialogfragment

I'm using the Twitter4j library to implement Twitter into my application. I have a `DialogFragment` which holds a `WebView` and allows the user to sign-in to their Twitter account with my app. It allows the user to sign-in but the callback URL never gets called. Instead, it will just keep displaying the sign-in button in the `DialogFragment` even though the user is already signed in. How can I get the callback URL to be called from a `DialogFragment` once the user has logged in?

Here is the layout of my Callback URL on the Twitter Developer site:

```
http://DOMAIN_NAME/SCHEME://HOST
```

And here is my `Activity` declaration within my manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <!-- Callback URL that Twitter will call which will direct us back into our app -->
            <data android:scheme=SCHEME android:host=HOST />    
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And within my `Activity` class I have a variable declared which holds the Callback URL:

```
String callbackUrl = "SCHEME://HOST";
```

Where the placeholders DOMAIN_NAME, SCHEME and HOST all correspond to their appropriate values.

And finally, the code within the login() method within my `Activity`:

```
    mRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(callbackUrl);

    InternetDialog webDialog = new InternetDialog();
    webDialog.setUrl(mRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL());

    webDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Twitter WebView");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the url you are getting after log in and then compare it with your callback url.

```
 private class TwitterWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // what is the value of url
        if (url.startsWith(AppConstants.CALLBACK_URL)) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
            mListener.onComplete(verifier,0);
            TwitterDialog.this.dismiss();

            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```